# Is it possible to use request js and cheerio js to build chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, requestjs

I want to build a web scraper plugin, I have used cheerio js and request js and have built a scraper that runs well in cmd line, but when I use the same code and run as chrome extension, its not working, so I would like to know if there is any way to use requestjs and cheeriojs to build chrome extension.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Chrome is not Node. Cheerio and requestjs are Node "things". You can intercept requests using the Chrome Extension API, and use jQuery as a "content" (injected into page) script that can send messages to your extension.

Comment: ok, I will check it out, thank you very much.